# Pass a variable to another function

Tags: javascript

I have this simple code:

```
function rotatecard(event){
    this.parent.parent.className = "rotated";
}

function rotatebutton() {
        "use strict";
        var cardbutton = document.getElementsByClassName('rotatebutton'), i;
        for (i = 0; i < cardbutton.length; i += 1) { bindEvt(cardbutton[i], "click", rotatecard) };
}
```

but in the rotatecard function `this` is reported as undefined. This is probably something basic but could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: bindevent code:

```
var bindEvt = (function () {
    "use strict";
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        return function (element, event, handler) {
            element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
        };
    }
    return function (element, event, handler) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
    };
}());
```

Comment: you probably want to address the clicked element. Look into the event object, it will be there as a property - instead of using `this`

Comment: bindEvt nice to see bind function. by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah. this probably refer to global window, I believe. try to use

```
event.target
```

if you need to catch clicked element

Answer (score 1):

If you want event target, you can get through `event.target`.

Incase if you want access the this object where handler is defined, then use `Function.prototype.bind`

```
bindEvt(cardbutton[i], "click", rotatecard.bind(this))
```